# How can I use an application class in order to start a service and use it in my activities?

Tags: java, android

I have a service, two activities and an extended application.
So my concern is, that if I implement the application in an activity it gets lost after I switch to the next activity. The idea is to use a service object in both of these activities with the help of my application class. So how do I have to implement it to have the same application class in both of my activities?

```
public class AppController extends Application {
boolean bound = false;
private static AppController mInstance;

private LocalService mBoundService;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        mBoundService = ((LocalService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        System.out.println("Connected!!!!");
        bound = true;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        mBoundService = null;
        bound = false;
    }
};


public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}
public void startService(){
    //start your service

}
public void stopService(){
    //stop service
}
public LocalService getService(){
    return mBoundService;
}
}
```

Comment: try using fragments so that service object won't get lost

Comment: AppController.getInstance(); is a null pointer if I use while I press a button.

Comment: In Activity use following code LocalService service =
 ((AppController)getApplication()).getService(); will do your job.

Comment: This also gives me null pointer @HimeshGoswami

Comment: Did you add AppController in your Androidmanifeast.xml file?

Comment: Also when I start my app I never get "Connected!!!" in my terminal..

Comment: Yes I did, but maybe I did it wrong. Let me recheck..

Comment: LocalService service = ((AppController)getApplication()).getService();
service.test(); <- nullpointer on my service instance

Comment: So my mBoundService is not getting started. The onServiceConnted does not get called. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to implement it in an application class like this

```
public class AppController extends Application {
boolean bound = false;
private static AppController mInstance;

private LocalService mBoundService;

/**
 * The Background Service, which is started to communicate with multiple activities
 */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        mBoundService = ((LocalService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        System.out.println("Connected!!!!");
        bound = true;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        mBoundService = null;
        bound = false;
    }
};


public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}


/**
 * With the start of app controller, the Service starts too
 */
public void onCreate() {
    startService(new Intent(this, LocalService.class));
    doBindService();
    super.onCreate();
}
public void startService(){

}
void doBindService() {
    bindService(new Intent(this,
            LocalService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

public void stopService(){
    //stop service
}
public LocalService getService(){
    return mBoundService;
}
public void test(){
    System.out.println("Test");
}
}
```

With a BroadCastReceiver you can then communicate with the activities.